# Whats the best way to tell if a required string is a npm package or a local file?

Tags: node.js, string, module, require

I'm looking for a way to check if the first argument to nodes `require` function is a local file or if it's a NPM module.

This is one possible solution I came up with where its checking the first character in the string.

```
const IS_NPM = /^(\w|\d|\@)/
const isLocal = (string) => !string.match(IS_NPM)
isLocal('lodash') // false
isLocal('./index.js') // true
```

Or

```
const IS_LOCAL = /^\.\.\/|^\.\/|^\//
const isLocal = (string) => string.match(IS_LOCAL)
isLocal('lodash') // false
isLocal('./index.js') // true
```

I'm not sure these cover all cases.

One think to keep in mind is if you match using path identifier it needs to work on any system mac, windows, linux.

What is the best way to check if a string is a NPM module or a local file?

Understandably if it's not local it doesn't necessarily mean it's a NPM module, because it can be a native node module like `crypto` or `url`.

Caveat: I'm looking for a sync solution that doesn't check NPM registry and doesn't check the file system. Just checks a given string and will determine if it's a local require or a absolute module require

Comment: You can't do it just by examining the string.  Finding an NPM module is a file system search process where you physically look in the file system following a sequence.  First it checks to see if it's a built-in module, then it follows a search path to see what it finds where.  If the path is a directory, then it has a different flow, including looking for a package.json file in that directory.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve by doing this?  We might have a better chance at helping you solve the real problem some other way.

Comment: FYI, here are the [whole set of rules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) for what `require()` is doing and looking for.

Comment: Plus for some things, there is ambiguity of whether the target is a "file" or a "module".  What does it mean to you if it's `require('../../someFile')`.  Is that a file or a module?  It could be either.  It could be part of a hierarchy of files in the current project or it could be an NPM module installed in a shared location.  You can't tell just by what the filename is.  You'd have to look in the file system, see if there's a package.json that points to an NPM repository.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for bringing that up, you make a good point, however i'm fully aware of how `require.resolve` works and how node resolves paths (with index, with package.json, with and without .main, ect) but that's different if the string isn't an actual path. I'm specifically talking about detecting whether or not something is going to resolve in the `node_modules` folder, or if package.json should be checked.

Comment: @jfriend00 The problem I am trying to solve is I'm building something similar to how `repl.it` automatically downloads npm modules from AST `require` or `import` declarations. I have the strings of all imported modules and need to know which are from `NPM` or which to resolve with / add to a `package.json` file.

Comment: @jfriend00 I also had to do this in a module I created `evalmd` https://github.com/reggi/evalmd/blob/master/src/eval-markdown.js#L321

It's come up a couple times within different projects would like to know best way of doing it.